# How to insert semicolon instead of newline exept every third newline

Tags: sed

I have input on every line:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

and I would like end result to be:

```
A;B;C
D;E;F
G
```

with `sed 's/$/;/'` I will replace end of line with semilocom, but I struggle with every nth part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 'N;N;s/\n/;/g' file
```

Output:

```
A;B;C
D;E;F
G
```

---

> `N`: append the next line of input into the pattern space
>
> `s/\n/;/g`: replace all newline characters with `;`

Answer (score 0):

with `paste`

```
paste -d';' - - - <<INPUT
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
INPUT
```

```
a;b;c
d;e;f
g;;
```

Comment: that was also my first attempt, but it was thrown away because of the last line `g;;`

Comment: Thank you. It works. There are always 3, sou g;; won't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

With all sed

```
sed -e '$b' -e 'N;$b' -e 'N;y/\n/;/' infile
```

Comment: I used shorter version, but yours gave me idea to solve my other problem. Thank you.